# Ebook files not visible?

Tags: mp3, ebook

I have a mp3 player which is suppose to support ebooks. I have put lots of ebooks on the disk. But when I go into the ebook mode and want to start a book the folders with the mp3 files is empy. Its like it doesnt show .mp3 files. However if I choose music mode I can play all the mp3 files on the disc. I have one folder for each ebook with lots of mp3 files in each folder.

Do ebooks need to be in a certain format or someting?

The mp3 player Im using is just called "MP3/WMA Player with Radio, model MP714AF".

Cheers
Wox

Answer (score 1):

That depends on the folder structure of your MP3 player - maybe it cannot find files inside a subfolder, or 'eBook mode' is looking in a different folder than 'Music mode'.

You can also use **[MakeitOne MP3 Album Maker](http://www.makeitone.net/audio/mp3albummaker.htm)** pack/join your MP3 files in a single file - whilst still allowing full playability, tag editing and unpacking.

[image]

Unlike similar programs MakeitOne MP3 Album Maker allows you to join the MP3 files and unpack them back to their original state without losing quality.

*MakeitOne MP3 Album Maker is freeware.*

Comment: Hey, I tried putting the mp3 files in the root folder and all kinds of different folders. I also tried to put in .wav files, but it didnt find that either. When I press "ebook" I just see the folder structure, but when I go into the folders they just appear empty...this is very weird...

Comment: i couldn't find any specifications for this particular mp3 player, have you tried to play any of the files in music mode? what is the bitrate of the audiobook MP3 files?

Comment: I found the problem, I was me beeing an idiot :P Ebook mean text files :P I thought it was audio books :P That is why the sounds files didnt show :)

Comment: i wasn't much better myself, 'eBook mode' shoulda tipped me off :)